# How to carry account fields on contacts fields

Tags: process-builder, cross-object

[image]

I want to carry below account field values from account onto contacts.

**Account Fields:**

```
HQ Country Country__c  Picklist              
State/Area  TR1__State_Area__c picklist      
City        HQ_City__c   text                
Street    HQ_Street__c  text                
Zip Code  Zip_Code__c  text
```

**Contact Fields:**

```
HQ Country HQ_Country__c  Picklist              
State/Area  State_Area__c picklist      
City        City__c   text                
Street    Street__c  text                
Zip Code  Zip_Code__c  text
```

I tried to use the process builder but I do not find the option to refer to account fields.

Please help

Regards,
Kunal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start the Process from change on Account, you cannot do it using Process Builder since it accepts only **String value** in the RHS of the Contact field name.

- By looking at the screenshot it looks like you started process builder from `Contact` object, so the process builder will run on any update on Contact.
- But what we want is if there is any change in Account the data needs to be updated on Contact (Account is Master data and Contact is slave, not vice versa)

**Best way is to use formula fields**

```
Contact.Zip_Code__c => Formula of TEXT(Account.Zip_Code__c)
Contact.City__c => Formula of TEXT(Account.City__c )
Contact.State__c => Formula of TEXT(Account.State__c )
```

**Reasons:**

- Avoids data integrity issue (if the user edits the contact field, data will be out of sync between Master and Detail object )
- Data is always uptodate
- Relationship is within the object definition and not in some adhoc process

Comment: Would I have to create new formula fields

Comment: Yeah you need to create formula fields in Contact object

Comment: Thanks brother. I think I would need you to help in future. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to edit those fields on Contacts then you can just use formula fields. Create formula field on Contact for each Account field that you need.

And if you want to do it with a process builder select Contact as your object if it starts the process and on **immediate actions** select your fields you want to update on Contact and select field type as **Reference** then you should be able to find related Account fields in **Value** part.

Comment: Hi @Oles I find Account Id under reference and not account

Comment: Hi @kunalgupta just click on that Account Id and you will see other Account fields after that. http://screencast.com/t/8H7tukq6

Answer (score 0):

It depend how you want to use.

Normally Account/Contacts fields are already linked through Parent Child relationship. If you need to access Account fields in Contact e:f in any formula just use

```
Account.HQ_Country__c
```